# Dedicate or devote

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to ask as to whether we can use the verbs **to devote** or **to commit** instead of **to dedicate**  without losing their senses in the original sentences in the following examples?

> This book is **dedicated to** my parents.
>
> A memorial stone was **dedicated t**o those who were killed in the
>   war.

Comment: To *dedicate* in this context has the sense of making a statement as a tribute, without anything tangible given to the subject of the statement. A book may be (and often is) dedicated to someone and sold or given to someone else. Likewise, memorial stones are often erected in public places, without transfer of title to the subject of the dedication. Neither *devote* nor *commit* has that sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use either "commited" or "devoted".

"Devoted" has two meanings - one is "very loyal" and another is "solely concerned with".

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/devoted

If a book is dedicated to someone it means that there's a message, for example, saying "For Steve" or something.  If it's devoted to Steve, then it means that most of the **content** of the book is **about Steve**.  Obviously a book is not capable of feeling loyalty towards someone so we don't need to worry about that definition.

So someone might write a book about rock music which is devoted to 1970s Glam Rock for example, meaning that's the focus of the book.  They might also **dedicate** it to their wife by writing "For Sarah" on the second page or something.

This is a common source of confusion, and you *will* see "devoted" used instead of "dedicated" sometimes, but it's wrong.

**committed** is more obviously, and simply wrong, and would make no sense at all in your example sentences.

Comment: I think the confusion is that devoted and committed can be synonyms for the adjective dedicated, but in both examples dedicated is a verb and devote and commit are not synonyms for dedicate.

Comment: Thank you.. so do the verbs " to dedicate and " to devote"  overlap  for a monument ?

Comment: @JonLarby I think you're right:  we could say that a very hard-working student is "devoted", "dedicated" or "committed" to her studies for example.

Comment: @Mrt no - the monument is the same as the book.  The dedication in both cases is a message saying "This thing was created for X".

Comment: You can dedicate, devote or commit **yourself** to something (such as your studies), but you can only dedicate **something else** (a book, a monument, etc). You can commit something to memory for instance, but that is a different meaning!

Comment: You're missing the relevant fact that 'devoted' is also the past participle of the transitive verb 'devote', which has as one sense ' 2. to set apart or dedicate by a solemn or formal act; consecrate' [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/devote)]. "I devote this book to" turns up internet examples. There _is_ a more solemn flavour than with 'dedicate'.

Comment: Thanks everybody.. I see some random results with " a monument devoted to ..." when I google . they are all wrong .. for example :https://www.visitestonia.com/en/monument-and-memorial-park-devoted-to-konstantin-pats-the-first-president-of-estonia

Comment: Perhaps, if a person or group of people appear **within the monument itself**, as with that Estonian example, it could be said to be devoted to that person.

Comment: @Jon Larby There is internet evidence showing that your claim that one can't use 'I devote this book to ...' is incorrect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth could that simply be internet evidence of people using words incorrectly?  Because I have also seen a huge amount of internet evidence of that nature.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - "I devote this book to" comes up with 122 results in Google, "I dedicate this book to" comes up with 79,200 results. The first one just sounds wrong to me, but I guess it sounds acceptable to a few people.

Comment: @Max Williams That is doubtful, because there is a greatly increased number for "devote this book to".

Comment: @JonLarby I find that "I devote this book to" comes up with 1710 results in a Google search, and "devote this book to" with 14 100.  Not as many as the 157 000 for "dedicate this book to", but not negligible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth google also has 557,000 results for "thanks alot" and 82,000 results for "no your wrong".  Is that evidence for their correctness?

Comment: It's better evidence than you provide for 'No, you can't use either "commited" or "devoted" ', failing to give the pertinent definition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I referenced a dictionary for "devoted" which I think is better than a google search results count.  I didn't bother to explain why committed is wrong, so you have me there.

Comment: But in saying ' "Devoted" has two meanings – one is "very loyal" and another is "solely concerned with" ' you're giving definitions for the adjective, whereas 'This book is dedicated / devoted to ...' doesn't use the adjective. It's like saying 'It was a miracle that anyone survived in the telescoped cars' is wrong because none of the observers had an optical instrument designed to make distant objects appear nearer.